# Hive always create mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I'm been using hive at my work, when i run a select like this

```
"Select * from TABLENAME"
```

hive executes a mapreduce job and  when I run

```
"Select * from TABLENAME LIMIT X" independently of x.
```

hive doesn't execute mapreduce jobs.

I use hive 1.2.1, HDP 2.3.0, hue 2.6.1 and hadoop 2.7.1

Any ideas about this fact?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908203/can-you-explain-when-and-why-mapreduce-is-invoked-in-hive/31124594#31124594

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908203/can-you-explain-when-and-why-mapreduce-is-invoked-in-hive/31124594#31124594

Comment: My case is different, because a simple query "select * from TABLE" executes mapreduce job instead of reading from HDFS. I know how hive and mapreduce work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table;
```

Requires no map nor reduce.  There is no filter(where statement) or aggregation function here.  This query simply reads from HDFS.

Answer (score -1):

This is hive's essential task. It is just an abstraction to map-reduce jobs. The former facebook engineers had to write 100s of map-reduce jobs for ad-hoc analysis and map-reduce jobs are somewhat a pain in the ass. So they abstracted it by an sql-language that will be translated in map-reduce jobs.

This is the same with Pig (yahoo).

P.S Some queries are so easy that they aren't translated to map-reduce jobs but are executed locally on one node as far as i know

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Actually it is a wrong answer. You could always see the number of mappers and reducers while running. Abstraction has nothing to do here with his query!

Comment: yes that is right i did not read the question correctly. Sorry