# Why Hive does not use MapReduce in some cases where it is expected to?

Tags: hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I created an AWS EMR cluster, SSH'ed to the master node, started Hive, and then created an external table from data in an AWS S3 bucket. But on some queries that I expect some mapper or reducer jobs need to be performed, it doesn't do that. e.x. for the following query I expect some mapper job be performed because we are filtering to two columns:

```
 SELECT item, store FROM tt3 LIMIT 10;
```

But it doesn't, and return the results quickly.
`explain` command confirms that:

```
Stage-0   Fetch Operator
    limit:10
    Limit [LIM_2]
      Number of rows:10
      Select Operator [SEL_1]
        Output:["_col0","_col1"]
        TableScan [TS_0]
          Output:["item","store"]
```

It works as expected on the query `select count(*) from tt3;` and runs MapReduce jobs first.

Output of `EXPLAIN COUNT(*) FROM tt3;`

```
Vertex dependency in root stage
Reducer 2 <- Map 1 (CUSTOM_SIMPLE_EDGE)

Stage-0
  Fetch Operator
    limit:-1
    Stage-1
      Reducer 2
      File Output Operator [FS_6]
        Group By Operator [GBY_4] (rows=1 width=8)
          Output:["_col0"],aggregations:["count(VALUE._col0)"]
        <-Map 1 [CUSTOM_SIMPLE_EDGE]
          PARTITION_ONLY_SHUFFLE [RS_3]
            Group By Operator [GBY_2] (rows=1 width=8)
              Output:["_col0"],aggregations:["count()"]
              Select Operator [SEL_1] (rows=1 width=211312928)
                TableScan [TS_0] (rows=1 width=211312928)
                  default@tt3,tt3,Tbl:COMPLETE,Col:COMPLETE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Expected behavior from Hive.

in hive if you do simple query like `select * from table` there will be no map reduce job is going to run as we are just dumping the data from HDFS.

```
Hive# select * from foo;
+---------+-----------+----------+--+
| foo.id  | foo.name  | foo.age  |
+---------+-----------+----------+--+
| 1       | a         | 10       |
| 2       | a         | 10       |
| 3       | b         | 10       |
| 4       | c         | 20       |
+---------+-----------+----------+--+
4 rows selected (0.116 seconds)
```

When ever you do **aggregations** then the `reducer` phase will be executed along with `map` phase.

```
Hive# select count(*) from table group by name;
INFO  : Map 1: 0/1      Reducer 2: 0/2
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1  Reducer 2: 0/2
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1  Reducer 2: 0/2
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1  Reducer 2: 0/2
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1  Reducer 2: 0/2
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 0/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 0(+1)/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 1/1
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 2    |
| 1    |
| 1    |
+------+--+
3 rows selected (13.709 seconds)
```

We can add another reducer phase to above query by adding order by clause to it

```
Hive# select count(*) cnt from foo group by name order by cnt;
INFO  : Map 1: 0/1      Reducer 2: 0/2  Reducer 3: 0/1
INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1  Reducer 2: 0/2  Reducer 3: 0/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 0/1  Reducer 3: 0/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 0(+1)/1      Reducer 3: 0/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 1/1  Reducer 3: 0(+1)/1
INFO  : Map 1: 1/1      Reducer 2: 1/1  Reducer 3: 1/1
+------+--+
| cnt  |
+------+--+
| 1    |
| 1    |
| 2    |
+------+--+
```

You can see **2 reducer phases** are done because after **aggregating** we are doing order by to the results

```
Map1 phase:- Loads the data from HDFS.

Reduer2:- Will does aggregation

Reducer 3:- after aggregation it will order the results to ascending order.
```

if you do explain on the above query

```
Hive# explain select count(*) cnt from foo group by name order by cnt;
 Vertex dependency in root stage     
 Reducer 2 <- Map 1 (SIMPLE_EDGE)    
 Reducer 3 <- Reducer 2 (SIMPLE_EDGE)
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141606/hive-queries-use-only-mappers-or-only-reducers.html) link regards to get familiar when Hive Uses Map/Reduce side jobs.

Comment: My example (`select item, store from tt3;`) is different from yours (`select * from table;`). In your example there is no map or reduce job involved, but in mine, there should be a map job. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908203/can-you-explain-when-and-why-mapreduce-is-invoked-in-hive) post.